# How to use onClickListener method in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my project i use `viewPager` for show some `fragments`.
In one of `fragments` i want **click** on button.
I write below codes but when **click** on `button` not call `onClickListener` and not show `Toast` for me!

**My codes in fragment :**

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list_item = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
                list_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (clickFlag) {
                            AuctionTodayListAdapter adapter = new AuctionTodayListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_auction_large_new, Constants.auction.getToday());
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            clickFlag = false;
                            list_item.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_icon);
                            Toast.makeText(context, ""+clickFlag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            AuctionTodayListAdapter adapter = new AuctionTodayListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_auction_normal_soon, Constants.auction.getToday());
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            clickFlag = true;
                            list_item.setImageResource(R.drawable.list);
                            Toast.makeText(context, ""+clickFlag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you overriding `setUserVisibleHint` to set up a click listener?

---

UPDATE:
`setUserVisibleHint` has nothing to do with toolbar buttons ... that method is for *you* to call to let the system know the fragment is not visible. It's not normally called by the system, which is why your toast is never shown.

If the button you're trying to find is a toolbar item, you need to interact with it using the [onCreateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) and [onOptionsItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) methods instead.

---

This is the sort of thing one does in onCreateView:

```
@Override
View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = // inflate view from layout resource
  list_item = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item); // Get toolbar item
  list_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      // Do you click stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Then, if you only want to interact with this button when this fragment is active, you can show and hide it in onStart() and onStop, respectively.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  list_item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  list_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Because this button into toolbar and toolbar has into mainActivity. i want when click on this button just change in current fragment not all fragments

Comment: i use custom button in toolbar (not use menu in toolbar). hey my friend if i write clickListener method in fragment in onCreate set this change on all fragments! but i want just set on current fragment. can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: Show / hide the button in onStart() / onStop(). See updated answer.